# Obervable.create not triggering in angular5 with ngrx

Tags: angular5, observable, ngrx

My effect is:

```
  @Effect({dispatch: false})   /* sends request to httpService with params as login credentials on instance of loginAction. */
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .instanceOf(LoginActions.LoginAction)
    .switchMap(
      action => {
        return this.loginHttpService.login(action.payload)
          .map( (res: any) => {
            if (res && res.message !== 'Invalid Login') {
                const firstName = res.firstName;
                const lastName = res.lastName;
                this.tokenService.setToken(res.jwt);
                this.tokenService.setFirstName(firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1));
                this.tokenService.setLastName(lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName .slice(1));
                this.tokenService.setId(res.id);
                this.tokenService.setAvatar(firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase());

                const permissions = res.roles
                this.tokenService.setUserRoles(permissions)
                return Observable.create(observer => {
                  console.log('in observable')
                  this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(permissions, () => {
                    observer.next({
                      type: 'string'
                    });
                    console.log('here we go')
                    this.store.dispatch(new LoginActions.LoginSuccessAction({user: res}))
                    return observer.complete();

                  })
                })
            }
          })
          .catch( (e:any)  => {
            this.store.dispatch(new LoginActions.LoginFailureAction(true));

            return Observable.create(observer => {
              return observer.complete();
            }) 
        });
      });
```

The `in observable` log never fires. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but I don't understand why you need to create a new Observable.

In this kind of situation, here is what I'm used to do :

```js
  @Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$
    .ofType<LoginAction.LoginAction>(LoginActions.LOGIN_ACTION)
    .pipe(
      map(action => action.payload),
      switchMap(payload => {
        return this.loginHttpService.login(payload)
          .map(userLogged => {
            return new LoginActions.LoginSuccessAction({user: userLogged});
          })
          .catch(error => {
            return new LoginActions.LoginFailureAction(true);
          });
      })
    );

  @Effect()
  loginSuccess$ = this.actions$
    .ofType<LoginAction.LoginSuccess>(LoginActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS)
    .pipe(
      map(action => action.payload),
      switchMap(payload => {
        return this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(payload.user)
          .map(permissions => {
            return new LoginActions.PermissionsLoaded(permissions);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            return new LoginActions.PermissionsLoadingFailed();
          })
        })
    );
```

If existing `loadPermissions` method doesn't return an `Observable`, a new method as below can do the job :

```js
loadPermissions(user): Observable<Permissions> {
   return Observable.create(observer => {
      loadPermissionsWithCallback(user, (response) => {
         observer.next(response);
         return observer.complete();
      });
   });
}
```

It's a chain of actions. LOGIN_ACTION -> LOGIN_SUCCESS -> PERMISSIONS_LOADED.
User is fully logged when action `PERMISSIONS_LOADED` is dispatched.
Each service method (`login` and `loadPermissions`) should return an Observable, and it's the case with new HttpClientModule.

Of course, it's just a simplified and incomplete example... Hope this will help you a little bit.

Comment: It seems that the `.map` function expects an observable?

Comment: The `.map` expects an `Observable` to be returned apparently?

Comment: Effects are `Observable` of actions, so you should return an action into `.map`. Or you can also return an other `Observable` of actions with `switchMap` like in the previous example. In your case, if you divide the workflow into multiple actions it will be simpler to trace and debug. You'll be able to see the steps into redux devtools also. And also it could be evolutive by plug in future actions or behaviours on it.

Comment: `loadPermissions` does not return an Observable - I think that's the problem

Comment: have you access to the implementation ? If yes you could change it to return an `Observable`. If you're using HttpModule, check new HttpClientModule. If not, you could imagine to create a new service method which is calling itself `loadPermissions` and return an Observable. Your effect will remain simple and maintainable.

Comment: How can I have something call `loadPermissions` and return an Observable since `loadPermissions` uses a callback?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You were on the good way, I understand now why you were created an `Observable`. But you should always return an `Action`. Observable is like a stream.